# How to make Windows use always the latest CLR for .Net assemblies?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, .net-framework

Days ago I saw a very useful registry value that instructs Windows to use always the last CLR version installed, this way the user does not need to have older versions of .NetFx installed in the system to run older applications targeting those older .Net Framework versions like the always annonying .NetFx 3.5.

I tested it and it works as expected. The problem is that I lost the value and the website on which I seen this value, I don't remember it and I put my effort to find it again in Google around the MSDN docs and random Windows personalization forums with no luck.

My question is to know again the details of that registry value I reffered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be as simple as doing the following:

> 1. Open `Regedit`
> 2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` (64-bit)
>
>    2b. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\.NETFramework` (32-bit)
> 3. Create a new `DWORD` value
> 4. Set the name to `OnlyUseLatestCLR` and set value as `1` (decimal)

- [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=force+windows+to+Use+always+last+CLR+registry+value)
- [Relevant Source](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-695707.html)
- [Relevant Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime)